# shuffle between objects in the same collection using geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]i want to shuffle between objects in the same collection using geo nodes , i'm newpie to geo nodes so the problem is i saw many videos talking about shuffling but the problem is they use a plane then instance on points , but for me i want to shuffle with my real objects locations , like if i made a roof tiles with specific locations , i want to shuffle between them to not have any repetetion anymore if i want to rescale my roof , like if i want to duplicate my roof tiles  , geo nodes will always ensure that there will be no repetition in the order of objects

Edit :
Like those roof tiles, what can i do to shuffle between them to get variation of the shape [image]

this is mo geo nodes :
[image]

Comment: please add an image with a sketch to make it clear how it should look like. thx. also your GN node tree would help so we can see what you did. thx.

Comment: tbh to me it makes no sense to use the real object location for parts of a roof. Can u explain this a bit more pls?

Comment: Do you really want 200+ objects, that you have to move manually ? What about if you want to add a *Bevel* to all tiles ? Or reshape your roof ? I'm unable to see why you wouldn't want to use *Instances* and *Points*.

Comment: U don't understand me well, i already made a big roof tiles for a roman palace but the repetition in shape is there, and i want to use geo nodes to shuffle between them to break that repetition

Comment: I've looked at your screenshots and I don't see any repetition in shapes. What is it exactly you want to achieve here ? Note that randomness (*Random Value* node) will never guarantee the absence of repetition.

Comment: That's not my roof i just model these shapes to test my geo nodes, and i will use a collection of my roof tiles when i found the solution, the problem here that i want to use my collection as a real input not just an instance on something else. Or let's say i want to instance all my collection of roof tiles with it's position without any change

Comment: So basically, you want 100+ different objects, each one using a random geometry from a set of tiles you've created ?

Comment: look at my roof tiles in the image above , there is an obvious repetition on it , and i have many complex roofs that i had to put tiles on it , so it will be very hard to rearrange everything from scratch , i just want to shuffle between their positions without any change in the stack position itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before formulating my answer, I want to adress 2 points which are important.

*I wouldn't recommend working with as many objects as your example. There is nothing in your example that cannot be easily achieve with nodes. What if you want to change the slope of your roof ?*

*Keep in mind that randomness will also produce repetitions. Not a regular one as in your question, but for example 2 adjacent tiles can have the same random value.*

#### Pick random objects from collection

There is one texture which doesn't contain any kind of repetition or regularity : *White Noise*. By sampling this texture based on the position of the current object, you'll be sure to have different random values as long as **no 2 objects have the same location**. In that case they would have the same tile, with my answer.

Here is a setup that achieves that. On the left are your few tiles you have modelled, on the right side is your roof.

[image]

**Warning : your objects will flicker when moving them. Can be uncomfortable or even harmful if you're sensitive to fast changing colors.**

The idea is to load all objects from the collection, then get a random ID and delete everything else, based on the *Instance* index.

#### Copy Geometry Node to multiple objects

Now, assuming you have your many objects and this node tree on one of them :

- Select all objects that need this Geometry Node
- Have the object with the node tree be *active* (highlighted by a lighter shade of orange). If it is not already active, just <kbd>Maj</kbd>+click this object.
- Then click on the drop-down menu of the modifier, and *Copy to Selected*

Before copying :

[image]

After copying :

[image]

Now all of your objects use the same Geometry Node. You can select any of them, they all share the same node tree.

Comment: thank you so much , it worked perfectly