# Dealing with random scattering

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes, procedural

How can I having a different seed for each duplicate mesh ? Ex: If I duplicate my plane, how can I have my plane.002 a different seed than my original plane while keeping the same geometry node set up ?
Scattering seed are the same on my 2 planes and I want it to be different for each plane.

[image: myimage]

[image: mypicture2]

Comment: you should at least show the node setup, that we can see how you duplicate your mesh. and if you wanna be nice, you provide a blend file so we don't have to build it ourselves. there are several ways to duplicate, so pls improve/clarify your setup. thx.

Comment: Do you mean duplicates made outside the GN group, or duplicates made inside the GN group?

Comment: I search to be able to shift+D my mesh with GN group and having a different seeds on it. Sorry if it's not clear :/

Comment: You can use *Self Object > Object Info > White noise* to get a random float [0,1] per location, similar to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314411/shuffle-between-objects-in-the-same-collection-using-geo-nodes/314430#314430.

Comment: You can connect the *Seed* socket to the *Group Input* node and then change the value per copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately your question isn't clear, but if you just did a "simple" duplicate, you can do it like this:

[image]

So just plug in the duplicate index into your seed.